# navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia Illegal Invocation error

Tags: javascript, jquery, getusermedia

I am using this code in a project I'm working on to record an audio file on the user's end and then upload it directly to the server all from one page... For some reason I get an Illegal Invocation error when I run this code. I know this means there's a context error, but I'm not exactly sure where it's coming from...

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: true
  })
  .then(function(stream) {
    recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

    const chunks = [];

    recorder.onstop = (e) => {
      const blob = new Blob(chunks, {
        type: "audio/wav;codecs=MS_PCM"
      });
      var fileUpload = new FormData();
      fileUpload.append("fileToUpload", blob, "audio.wav");
      $.post("upload.php", fileUpload);
    };

    recorder.ondataavailable = (e) => {
      chunks.push(e.data);
    };

    recorder.start();
  });
```

If anyone has any ideas... they would obviously be appreciated!

Comment: FWIW, this isn't a .wav file you're uploading. It's probably an `audio/opus` file. You set the media type of your recording in an option to the [MediaRecorder ctor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder/MediaRecorder), not the Blob ctor.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the error was coming from the call to the event "e.data" variable from within the jQuery context. Doing a simple ajax XHR fixed the issue quickly...

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", 'upload.php', true);
xhr.send(fileUpload);
```

Putting it together... it works without error now!

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: true
  })
  .then(function(stream) {
    audioStream = stream;
    recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

    const chunks = [];

    recorder.onstop = (e) => {
      const blob = new Blob(chunks, {
        type: "audio/wav;codecs=MS_PCM"
      });
      var fileUpload = new FormData();
      fileUpload.append("fileToUpload", blob, "audio.wav");
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open("POST", 'upload.php', true);
      xhr.send(fileUpload);
    };

    recorder.ondataavailable = (e) => {
      chunks.push(e.data);
    };

    recorder.start();
  });
```

Comment: You might just want to try to use `fetch` instead of `XMLHttpRequest`...

Comment: I thought about using `fetch`, but at the end of the day, it's not really that much simpler, and I'm far more familiar with xhr than I am with `fetch`